# how can i call a javascript function when an ASP.net validation summary is filled

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationsummary

i have a validationSummary in my page. i want to call a javascript function after the validationSummary is filled. how can i achieve this?

i think i should add an attribute in the code behind, but i can't figure out what is the attribute's key.

any help?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to call the javascript function `Page_ClientValidate()` to initiate the ASP.NET validation wired to your page controls.  Once this is called, the `Page_IsValid` boolean value will be properly set.

Here is an example of how I am using it.  If ASP.NET validation is successful, I disable the button, otherwise the button remains enabled and the validation summary is displayed to the user.  The `OnClientClick` is from a ASP:Button control.

```
OnClientClick="javascript:Page_ClientValidate(); if (Page_IsValid==true) { this.disabled=true; }"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but in fact it print two time the ValidationSummary's ShowMessageBox :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. It is, however, possible to intercept validation by setting `OnClientClick` on the controls that do postbacks. Then you can check the global JavaScript variable `Page_IsValid` for the validation result.

One thing to keep in mind is that, when there are no validators on a page, `Page_IsValid` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I started to implement the solution by @EverettEvola but also where the validation logic was being called multiple times and displaying multiple ValidationSummary popups. My solution was as follows:

On the button (in my case the button was a submit button)

```
OnClientClick="return CustomValidationOnClick()"
```

And the CustomValidationOnClick()

```
function CustomValidationOnClick(source, args) {

    //Manually kickoff page validation
    //This call will display the Validation summary popup if page is invalid
    Page_ClientValidate();

    //Page_IsValid set by the result of the Page_ClientValidate() call
    if (Page_IsValid == true) {
        this.disabled=true;
        return true; //if Submit button return true to continue form submit
    }
    else {
       //do whatever here
       return false; //if Submit button return false to cancel form submit
    }
}
```