# Can I call a function after a ValidationSummary?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, validation

I have a `ValidationSummary` on client side (which should be called by asp:LinkButton) that check my `RequiredFieldValidator` and `CustomValidator` :

```
<asp:ValidationSummary 
    ID="valSum" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="label" 
    HeaderText="There are these errors:" 
    ShowSummary="False" 
    ShowMessageBox="True" 
    EnableClientScript="True" 
    DisplayMode="BulletList">
</asp:ValidationSummary>
```

and I need, if there are the errors (so there are empty fields or the custom validators fail) call another javascript function.

I really hope that this is possible on .NET 3.5, right?

I've read a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060220/how-can-i-call-a-javascript-function-when-an-asp-net-validation-summary-is-fille), but is not clear at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You will need to change the OnClientClick property of your linkbutton and/or other controls causing the validation to perform. Also put your CausesValidation property to false.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return DoValidation('');" ... />
```

Javascript function:

```
 function DoValidation(validationGroup) {
      var isValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
      if (!isValid){
         isValid = DoSomethingElse();
      }
     return isValid;
 }
```

If you want to only validate a group you can pass the name of the group to the 'DoValidation' function.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return DoValidation('NameOfGroup');" ... />
```

Comment: Updated the example to is not valid. Sorry for that.

Comment: It also call twice ShowBox for the Validator Summary, that's why you need a `return false;` after calling `return DoValidation('');` Anyway thanks, it works!

Comment: Even if you use a CausesValidation="false". Please let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: You could also let the DoSomethingElse return false.

Answer (score 8):

Place this script at the page's end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var originalValidationSummaryOnSubmit = ValidationSummaryOnSubmit;
     ValidationSummaryOnSubmit = function (validationGroup) {
          originalValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);

          if (Page_IsValid === false) {
               alert("boo!");
          }
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Excelent! Solved my problem! One question: `validationGroup` is the only parameter of `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit`? How can I get the name/id of the button that had trigger the validation?